# Adding a column derived from a CASE function to a normal table column

Tags: sql

I am trying to add the output of a column derived from a CASE statement ([Gift Aid Total] to a standard table column (bd.paymentamount). In this case, the derived column equals a monetary value and I want to add it to another monetary value within a table.

I have tried standard SQL code (see below) to add the two columns together.

```
select co.contacttype, co.firstname+' '+co.keyname [Name], bd.incometype, bd.paymentamount, 

CASE WHEN (gd.GADstatus)='Active' THEN bd.paymentamount*0.25 
ELSE '0'
END AS [GAT],

[GAT]+bd.paymentamount,

bd.dateofpayment [Payment Date]

from contact co
left join batchdetail bd on co.serialnumber=bd.serialnumber
left join GIFTAID_CURRENTDECLARATION AS gd ON bd.SERIALNUMBER=gd.SERIALNUMBER
where bd.DATEOFPAYMENT BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2019-08-31'
```

When I try to add these two columns together I receive an error saying Invalid column name 'GAT'.

I would like the code to add both columns together and show the total in a new third column.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL statements cannot refer to an alias defined in the `SELECT` in the same query's `SELECT`, `FROM`, or `WHERE` clauses (and others depending on the database).  For the `SELECT` the reason is simple:  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.

This used to be solved using CTEs or subqueries.  My preferred method is a lateral join.  The syntax depends on the database.  In SQL Server, it looks like this:

```
select co.contacttype, (co.firstname + ' ' + co.keyname) as [Name],
       bd.incometype, bd.paymentamount, v.gat,
       v.gat + bd.paymentamount,
       bd.dateofpayment as [Payment Date]
from contact co left join
     batchdetail bd
     on co.serialnumber = bd.serialnumber left join
     GIFTAID_CURRENTDECLARATION gd
     on bd.SERIALNUMBER = gd.SERIALNUMBER cross apply
     (values (CASE WHEN gd.GADstatus ='Active' THEN bd.paymentamount * 0.25 
ELSE 0 END)
     ) v(gat)
where bd.DATEOFPAYMENT BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2019-08-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use an alias in the same level because all the field are process at the same time and at that moment the alias still doesn't exists

This is wrong

```
SELECT 1 as one, one + one as two
```

Instead you need to first create the alias and then use in in a subquery

```
 SELECT one +  one as two
 FROM ( SELECT 1 as one ) as t
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/89983)**